# Why am I getting an unexpected token error in jQuery 1.4.4.min file?

Tags: jquery

Why am I getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
c.b.extend.globalEval                          jquery-1.4.4.min.js:32
c.extend.httpData                              jquery-1.4.4.min.js:144
c.extend.ajax.L.w.onreadystatechange           jquery-1.4.4.min.js:140
```

This error doesn't point me to a place in my JS that is triggering this issue. Just the jQuery min file.

How do I debug this and fix it ?

Edit1: Here are some screenshots of my call stack around this error. Still not sure though, which file has the syntax error that is being called by jQuery.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Edit 2:

Here are some of my AJAX calls:

```
$('form#project-ajax-form').submit(function(){
    if(compv.steps.selectedClient.id != null){
    $('input#project_client_id').val(compv.steps.selectedClient.id);
        console.debug("Project Client Value: " + $('input#project_client_id').val());
        return true;
    }
    console.debug("Project Client Value not found");
    compv.tools.clientError();
    return false;
});    
$('#project-ajax-form')
        .bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
        compv.updateStepView('project', xhr);
});

$('#client-ajax-form')
    .bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    console.log("Calling Step View");
    compv.updateStepView('client', xhr);
});

$('form#stage-ajax-form').submit(function(){
if(compv.steps.selectedProject.id != null){
$('input#stage_project_id').val(compv.steps.selectedProject.id);
    console.debug("Stage Project Value: " + $('input#stage_project_id').val());
    return true;
}
console.debug("Stage Project Value not found");
compv.tools.clientError();
return false;
});
$('#stage-ajax-form')
    .bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
    compv.updateStepView('stage', xhr);
});

$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");
  }
});

$('.ajax-form')
.bind("ajax:success", function(evt, data, status, xhr){
  var $form = $(this);
    console.log("Form Success: %s", $(this).attr('id'));

  // Reset fields and any validation errors, so form can be used again, but leave hidden_field values intact.
  $form.find('textarea,input[type="text"],input[type="file"]').val("");
  $form.find('div.validation-error').empty();
})
.bind("ajax:failure", function(evt, xhr, status, error){
  var $form = $(this),
      errors,
      errorText;
    console.log("Form Failure: %s", $(this).attr('id'));

  try {
    // Populate errorText with the comment errors
    errors = $.parseJSON(xhr.responseText);
  } catch(err) {
    // If the responseText is not valid JSON (like if a 500 exception was thrown), populate errors with a generic error message.
    console.error("Server Error for Form: %s", $(this).attr('id'));
    errors = {"Server Error": "Please reload the page and try again"};
  }

  // Build an unordered list from the list of errors
  errorText = "There were errors: \n<ul>";

  for ( error in errors ) {
    errorText += "<li>" + error + ': ' + errors[error] + "</li> ";
  }

  errorText += "</ul>";

  // Insert error list into form
  var errorDiv = $form.find("div.validation-error");
  errorDiv.html(errorText);
  errorDiv.show(300);
});
```

Comment: You should be able to see the call stack, and consequently what led to the error, in a script debugger, e.g. the one built into Chrome.

Comment: @jamietre Sorry if this is a dumb question, but how do I see that call stack in Chrome on OS X ? As in, where do I look exactly ? Thanks.

Comment: Right-click, "Inspect Element," Scripts, then there's a "Call Stack" section on the right. If the script debugger is open when the error happens it will be there already.

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshots of my call stack. Not sure how to find script being called with the syntax error though. This is the first time I am doing this, so I apologize if the question is very n00bish and obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in another question: [Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token - jQuery - Help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249316/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-jquery-help)

Answer (score 3):

The callstack indicates that jQuery is calling `eval` from the response to an AJAX request.

You're calling `getScript` for a Javascript file with a syntax error.

---

To answer your stated question, you can debug this by switching to the debug version of jQuery (not `.min`) and using a debugger, such as Firebug or Chrome's Developer Tools.

Comment: Check the AJAX response in Firebug or Chrome.

Comment: I have updated the question with screenshots of my call stack. Not sure how to find script being called with the syntax error though. This is the first time I am doing this, so I apologize if the question is very n00bish and obvious. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @marc: Look at the `data` variable.  That's HTML, not Javascript.  Why do you think it's a script?

Comment: I have no particular reason to believe it is a script - other than any time I have had these issues in the past, it has always been associated with a script. But, I am pretty new at this...soo....that being said, I have a data attribute as part of various HTML tags and I have a local data variable in my JS. But I feel like I am shooting in the dark, not know which one I should be looking at. How do I get more specific info ?

Comment: This would happen if you call `$.getScript` on something that returns HTML.  Check your AJAX code.

Comment: Just searched all my files for `getScript` and the only place they come up are in the jQuery 1.4.4 files (min + uncompressed)

Comment: Then where are you making an AJAX call?

Comment: I have updated the question with some of my AJAX calls. Let me know if anything jumps out at you.