# What are some good JS debugging tools?

Tags: javascript, debugging

Aside from Chrome Developer Tools and Firebug in Firefox, are there other tools that I can use to debug my client-side JS ?

Comment: If you mention what short-comings you are trying to overcome, people can offer more help.

Comment: It's kinda hard to describe, but this is what I am dealing with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5221150/why-am-i-getting-an-unexpected-token-error-in-jquery-1-4-4-min-file and I find it a bit difficult to step through each stage and find exactly where my issue is - given that the JS console in Chrome is not telling me much else other than just jQuery lines. But I am pretty certain it's not the jQuery library that is at fault, and more likely it is my script. So that's what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript)

[JavaScript Debugger](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/javascript-debugger/) (Firefox Extension)

You can also do this in [Visual Studio](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/19/vs-2008-javascript-debugging.aspx) but I haven't tried it, so I can't vouch for it.

Comment: also chrome has built in tools, but firebug is the greatest

Comment: @stefan unfortunately, I have to agree, but there's really not much else out there.

Comment: *cough* you have much to learn ;)

Answer (score 3):

Similar question [Is there a single HTML5, JavaScript, and CSS debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445759/is-there-a-single-html5-javascript-and-css-debugger/4445828#4445828)

PhpStorm/WebStorm/Intellij have a built-in debugger that you can run from within the IDE http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/features/index.html

Comment: +1 for WebStorm, which also offers great static code analysis.

Comment: @Pumbaa80: It offers the best available static code analysis in the market, as far as I know. But it's not "great", I am tired of filing bugs with them and having to adjust my code style to match their code/doc parser.

Comment: Update: They have been fixing a number of the bugs I filed and their JSDoc type based suggestions are getting better and better

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by *debug*.

If you mean performance profiling/optimizing then nothing compares to [dynaTrace ajax edition](http://ajax.dynatrace.com/ajax/en/) which is head and shoulders above firebug or chromes developer tools - alas it only works with ie.

If you mean debug errors in your code, then using visual studio to trace errors is again head and shoulders over firebug.

If you just need ease of use for everyday testing firebug is a great tool tho :)

Comment: Looks like a FireFox version is in the works.

Comment: Can you reference a resource for using VS for javascript debugging? I have tried to make this work in the past, and have succeeded only in debugging inline javascript (e.g. in aspx/ascx), and only when using IE. Neither of which I do  much of. I would love to be able to but googling has just netted me dozens of the same question and lots of different answers involving having to change filenames, put scripts in particular places, having to manually attach to the process... it seemed a big headache so I gave up and use chrome and/or firebug.

Comment: @jaimetre: i have never tried using it with anything else than ie, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) + Chrome Developer Tools + Safari Developer Tools + IE8 Developer Tools is all you'll ever need.