# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token - jQuery - Help!

Tags: jquery

Please help me get to the bottom of this...the only file that this error is pointing to, is my jQuery file.

See the error I am receiving here.
[image]

How do I find the line in the file that is throwing this error ?

Edit2: Here is a screenshot after Nathan's suggestion of replacing `.js` with `.html` or nothing at all:
[image]

Comment: You need to provide your jQuery code, which causes this to fire. I guess that goes back to a `jsonp` call somewhere.

Comment: @jAndy I just created a test account so you can see the error live. I am pretty new to debugging ajax stuff, so do you mind logging in and seeing if you can give me some more direction as to where to look in my code, please? To replicate the error, click on the client name, then click on the project name, and then click on a stage name. You should see the errors in the JS console in Chrome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the data property listed in the debugger to the right, it looks like you are trying to eval() some HTML code as JavaScript. My guess is would be that your AJAX request is rendering an HTML error or pointing to the wrong URL, and not getting JS back.

Comment: I just created a test account so you can see the error live. I am pretty new to debugging ajax stuff, so do you mind logging in and seeing if you can give me some more direction as to where to look in my code, please? To replicate the error, click on the client name, then click on the project name, and then click on a stage name. You should see the errors in the JS console in Chrome.

Comment: @marcamillion It looks like you're setting `data-select-url` to `/stages/26/step.js`. The '.js' on the end of the URL is making Rails return the request with a Content-Type of 'text/javascript', which is causing jQuery to think it's valid JS that it should eval(). If you change the URL to be .html (or remove the extension entirely), then the error should go away. (You may need to adjust your routes to actually handle that correctly.)

Comment: @Nathan I may need to adjust my routes to actually handle what ? the .js or the .html ?

Comment: Btw Nathan. I tried what you suggested. I think you are definitely on to something. The error has changed, which indicates that is what is causing the error for sure. But now when I do `.html` or nothing, I get another error and it loads the entire page in the `Projects` pane. I have updated the question to include a screenshot.

Comment: Can you pastie the routes for this step in particular somewhere?

Comment: Nathan, see them here: https://gist.github.com/862611 I added a few extras. But the ones applicable are the ones with the prefix `step` (i.e. the first and last line in that gist).

Comment: The routes look right. What does the controller method look like?

Comment: It's redirecting because you have `format.html { redirect_to("/") }` in the handler. Remove that and change the format.js line to format.html instead, and it should work.

Comment: YESSSSS!!!!! DUDE. I don't think you understand HOW LONG I have been struggling with this. THANKS SOOOO MUCH. Seriously. ZOMG. It's easily been about 10 days, on this ONE DAMN issue!!!! Thanks VERY MUCH MAN. I truly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your entire file is throwing the error.

You're trying to execute some HTML as Javascript code.

Comment: I just created a test account so you can see the error live. I am pretty new to debugging ajax stuff, so do you mind logging in and seeing if you can give me some more direction as to where to look in my code, please? To replicate the error, click on the client name, then click on the project name, and then click on a stage name. You should see the errors in the JS console in Chrome.