# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp-2.1

I am encountering a problem similar to this:
[Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token - jQuery - Help!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249316/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-jquery-help)

I am using CakePHP 2.x to generate a jquery AJAX request. It works fine on my local setup, but fails on a production server, giving me an uncaught SyntaxError:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

This is the PHP:

```
// Get the select element by its generated id attribute.
echo $this->Js->get('#'.$equipment_code)->event(
    // Change in the dropdown selection
    'change',
    // Request an array of compatible brands (match model type)
    $this->Js->request(
        array('controller'=>'builds','action'=>'ajax_brands'),
        // Update the associated brand dropdown
        array('update' => $hashed_brand_code, 'dataExpression' => true, 'data' => '$("#'.$equipment_code.'").serialize()')
    )
);
```

Which generates this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#equipment-14-0").bind("change", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            data:$("#equipment-14-0").serialize(), 
            dataType:"html", 
            success:function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#brand-14-0").html(data);}, 
                url:"\/proj\/eztek-dev\/builds\/ajax_brands"
            });
            return false;
        });
    $("#brand-14-0").bind("change", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            data:$("#brand-14-0,#equipment-14-0").serialize(),
            dataType:"html", 
            success:function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#model-14-0").html(data);
            }, 
            url:"\/proj\/eztek-dev\/builds\/ajax_models"
        });
        return false;
    });
    $("#equipment-14-2").bind("change", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            data:$("#equipment-14-2").serialize(), 
            dataType:"html", 
            success:function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#brand-14-2").html(data);
            }, 
            url:"\/proj\/eztek-dev\/builds\/ajax_brands"
        });
        return false;
    });
    $("#brand-14-2").bind("change", function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            data:$("#brand-14-2,#equipment-14-2").serialize(), 
            dataType:"html", 
            success:function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#model-14-2").html(data);
            }, 
            url:"\/proj\/eztek-dev\/builds\/ajax_models"
        });
        return false;});
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

And here is the [image: stack trace]

I'd really appreciate any help you can offer, if there is any other information that would be useful, please let me know and I will put it up here asap.

Thank you!

EDIT:

Thank you all for your help. I have fixed the uncaught syntax error by removing unaccepted characters in the js files, however the AJAX still doesn't work on the production server. I get the following error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) 
{Domain name} /proj/eztek-dev/builds/ajax_brands?data%5BEzcomponent%5D%5B2%5D%5Bezmodel_type_id%5D=5
```

[image: Network requests]
<sub>(source: [resaraos.com](http://resaraos.com/proj/screenshot2.png))</sub>

Could something be going wrong with the serialize()?

Comment: Disable all Chrome extensions, and re-enable them one by one to see which extension caused the error.

Comment: What's your local server and production server operating system? What's the relative path of your app in local and production server?

Comment: Are you sure you're typing those URL's right, is this a linux server.

Comment: Rob W - The script still fails with all chrome extensions disabled, I get the same situation in Safari and Firefox, do you think an extension could be causing the error despite this? Thanks!

Comment: sємsєм - They are different in both cases:
Local server is OSX 10.6 with a relative url of /eztek-dev/
Production server is Debian with a relative url of /proj/eztek-dev/
Thanks!

Comment: I have reuploaded my app folder to /eztek-dev/ of my server, so my urls should? now be the same. I appear to get the same error with the ajax call.

Comment: why the backslashes in URL? Look in Network tab and see what happens to requests. Will see status, data sent, and returned ( if any), headers etc.

Comment: Charlietfl - I don't know as it was generated by the framework, I assume they escape the following forward slashes. They are present when I run it on my local server, which runs fine.

[Network request] (http://resaraos.com/proj/screenshot2.png)

Comment: I have solved the uncaught SyntaxError, but am still having problems with the AJAX - see edit above.

Comment: 500 status means server code problem

Comment: Ok, making sure that the RequestHandler component was included in my appcontroller had gotten rid of the 500 status, however the ajax still doesn't work...

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out that the way you generate your php code is quite im-practical.

```
$arr1 = array(
    'controller'=>'builds',
    'action'=>'ajax_brands'
);

$arr2 = array(
    'update' => $hashed_brand_code, 
    'dataExpression' => true, 
    'data' => '$("#'.$equipment_code.'").serialize()'
);

$jsRequest = $this->Js->request($arr1, $arr2);
$jsGet = $this->Js->get('#'.$equipment_code)->event('change', $jsRequest); // Change in the dropdown selection & update the associated brand dropdown

$echo $jsGet;
```

Something like would make sense.

Sorry for answering an old post (without really answering with a real answer to the question), this just really pierced my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Late hint for anyone stumbling upon this question:

This particular error is not specified by Chrome. Use Firefox (Firebug console) to get more info about the error.